# Is it possible to get Sublime Text's "Goto symbol" behavior on pressing Ctrl + R in Vim?

Tags: vim, sublime-text

In Sublime Text, when I have a file open and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, I get a type-ahead window with fuzzy matching on all function and class definitions in the file, making it possible for me to type some of the name of the function I want to jump to and quickly jump to it.

Could this be done in VIM? From what I've gathered, I can use CTags to make a tag file containing links to the functions, and then with cursor on a use of the function I can keystroke to jump to the definition. This is not quite what I want, because I want to be able to find the function regardless of where my cursor is positioned.

Is it possible to get Sublime Text's "Goto symbol" behavior on pressing Ctrl + R in Vim?

Answer (score 1):

The [Tagbar - Display tags of the current file ordered by scope](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) plugin provides a sidebar with all functions etc. of the current buffer, but you still have to search "conventionally" with `/` or other motions.

The [FuzzyFinder - buffer/file/command/tag/etc explorer with fuzzy matching](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) plugin has (among many more) a `:FufBufferTag` command that provides exactly what you want: Fuzzy matching as-you-type of all tags from the current buffer.

Comment: I figured fuzzy might have the functionality. Only one concern remains. Can these tags be generated automatically at runtime, so I don't have to bother with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get most if not all of the functionalty of that Sublime Text dialog with plugins like [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) or Unite.

CtrlP's `:CtrlPBufTag` command does exactly what you want, without prior generation of a `tags` file.

If you want to go lo-tech, you can try `:il[ist] func` then `:{line number}<CR>` or `:lvim func % | lw`.

Comment: Looks pretty solid. I'll be sure to give it a look over :)